# Terraform: output from multiple module calls

Tags: terraform, hcl

**Pseudo-code:**

```
module "foo-1" {
    source="./foo"
    input=1
}
module "foo-2" {
    source="./foo"
    input=2
}
module "foo-3"
    source="./foo"
    input=3
}
...etc...
```

(The module ./foo outputs a unique id based on the input value)

**Problem:**

I would like to be able to arbitrarily instantiate/call the ./foo module and have access to the unique id from each module instances.  I can't see a way to do this with Terraform as the output syntax either requires a unique val=expression per module instantiation.  Splat expressions on the module object (module.*.id) are unfortunately (and not surprisingly) not supported.

I'm guessing that this can't be done in terraform but would love to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because each of those modules is entirely separate from Terraform's perspective, to gather their results together into a single value will require writing an expression to describe that. For example:

```
locals {
  foos = [
    module.foo_1,
    module.foo_2,
    module.foo_3,
  ]
}
```

With a definition like that, elsewhere in your module you can then write an expression like `local.foos[*].id` to collect up all of the `ids` across all of the modules.

Comment: Thanks for the followup and suggestion, Martin.  Unfortunately, w/r to the above, it requires an update to the local array every time a new module instance is called which is what I'm trying/hoping to avoid as, in my real use case, each child module instance is in it's own .tf file in the calling module.

Comment: There is no automatic way for Terraform to understand that these modules all go together, so you have to tell it somehow. One alternative would be to use `count` or `for_each` in a single module block to systematically define multiple instances of the same module based on a collection, assuming their input variable definitions are similar enough to all come from the same source expressions.

Comment: Thanks again, Matin.  Yeah, I thought about loop operations but they won't work within the confines of the architecture nor in the output clock (as there's no way to collect all the modules).  I may just live with it until we are ready to re-architect the root module (setup the way it is to user TFE and minimize workspace license usage.